# How is there a potential difference when there is no voltage drop in a simple single battery circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Suppose we had a simple circuit where one end of a copper wire was connected to the negative terminal and the other end was connected to the positive terminal. If there is no voltage drop between any two parts of the wire, how is there a potential difference between the positive and negative terminals of the battery?

Consider the resistance of the copper wire negligible?

Comment: Your question is not clear, there is allways  a potential difference between the two poles of a battery, if the resistance of your wire is very low compared to the inner resistance of the batterie  the voltage will be very small

Comment: This is known as short circuiting. A fire may result.

Comment: What makes you think there is no voltage drop between the terminals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is no voltage drop between these two terminals then how is
> there a potential difference between the positive and negative
> terminals of the battery?

Refer to the figures below.

All real batteries have internal resistance, which is $R_b$ in the figures. The potential difference between the battery terminals, $V_T$, depends on $R_b$, the internally generated Emf of the battery, $E$, and the resistance of the circuit connected to the terminals as follows:

FIG 1:

When no circuit is connected to the terminals the terminal voltage $V_T$ equals the emf $E$ of the battery. That's because when no current flows there is no voltage drop across $R_b$ so all of the battery emf is across the terminals, or $V_{T}=E$. This is sometimes referred to as the "no load" voltage.

FIG 2:

When a circuit with resistance $R_L$ is connected to the terminals, current flows and there is a voltage drop across the internal resistance depending on the current to the load $R_L$. The terminal voltage $V_T$ is then the battery emf $E$ minus the drop across the internal resistance, $IR_{b}$, which is the voltage drop across the load.

FIG 3:

If a copper wire with theoretically zero resistance were connected across the terminals, then all of the battery emf $E$ will drop across the internal resistance $R_b$ making the terminal voltage $V_{T}=0$. But with the exception of superconductors, all conductors have resistance.

Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose we had a simple circuit where one end of a copper wire was connected to the negative terminal and the other end was connected to the positive terminal. If there is no voltage drop...

If a wire is connected between the positive and negative terminals of a battery, there will be a voltage drop through the wire equal to the potential difference of the battery terminals when heavy current is drawn from the battery. The voltage drop will not be $0$.

Comment: So if I measured the potential difference between two parts of the wire, considering the resistance of the wire to be negligible, there would be a voltage drop.

Comment: A quantity is negligible if you can ignore it and still arrive at fairly accurate results. In the case where a wire is connected across the terminals of a live battery, the resistance of the wire cannot be ignored.

Comment: If $R=0\Omega$, then $I=\lim_{R\to 0}\frac{V}{R}=\infty\rm\, A$, which is not physically reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting confused from the fact that the closed line integral of E is always zero in the absence of changing magnetic fields, as $\nabla × \vec{E} = 0$.

Remember this is a closed line integral, a line integral from the positive to negative terminal, is not a closed line integral.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misused the Ohm's law. I believe that you noted that for ideal wire $R_w=0\Omega$, for ideal battery $R_b=0\Omega$, and therefore $V=RI=(R_b+R_w)I=0\Omega\cdot I = 0\rm\, V$.

However, the ideal wire doesn't exist. It has some internal resistance. This applies to a battery as well. Hence, you will always have some resistance $R=R_b+R_w$.

As a sidenote, suppose we had $R=0\Omega$. Then, the current would be infinite, but that isn't possible.

Comment: Even if there was zero resistance wires, the potential drop would not be zero across the wire. That is a misaplication of ohms law. Which is a steady state solution involving the potential required for zero acceleration. Hence zero potential, as in a 0 resistance wire, zero potential is needed to maintain a constant current. The PD drop will be the batteries PD

Comment: @jensenpaull The first sentence refers to the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the battery, there is a corrosion-like chemical reaction. Positive ions migrate from a metal to another, provided there is a external wired connection between the poles. Without this connection, the reaction stops, because the electrical field due to the accumulation of charges balances the chemical potential.

If a copper wire with virtually zero resistance connects the poles, the reaction proceeds at its maximum speed, which depends on the kinetics of ions transportation. So, there is no contradiction in zero potential difference between the poles (which a voltmeter shows), zero electric field everywhere, and a constant flow of current. The source is the chemical potential between the elements inside the battery.